# Android gradle global constants

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, build

I'm trying in Gradle to load remote properties dynamically at every build, and use values in gradle files:

```
-settings.gradle
-build.gradle (project)
-build.gradle (module : lib)
-build.gradle (module : app)
```

I found a solution, but i don't know if it's the best one :

In settings.gradle, i recover properties like that:

```
//cfg is a java Properties class (key/value)
gradle.ext.cfg = Plugin.configureProject("url")
```

And i use in every gradle file like that (for example with applicationId in build.gradle(app) ):

```
applicationId gradle.ext.cfg.get("appId")
```

I tried to use rootProject.ext, but  it's not accessible in settings.grade.

I tried to create custom plugin but the only way to make accessible every where is to make static Properties inside and load it in settings.gradle, don't know if it's better..

Is it good to use gradle.ext like that in every .gradle ? It's working but maybe there is better solution.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

you can add this line `buildConfigField "boolean", "ISBOOLEAN", "false"` in your build.gradle like :

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
           //some code 
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ISBOOLEAN", "false"
          //somecode} }
```

and then a new java file called BuildConfig will be created containing your variables and then you can access your static variables.

Comment: Yes for java constants i do that, but i would like constants for every gradle files. I edit my post, i was not clear sorry